# Why can't I make a failover cluster using iSCSI for shared storage?

Tags: hyper-v, iscsi, failovercluster

I’m trying to build a 2-node failover cluster (sqlnode-1, sqlnode-02) using Server 2016 guest VMs in my Hyper-V-based lab.

The problem I have is that the cluster wizard doesn’t recognise my shared storage.

I’m trying to use iSCSI for the shared storage. I’ve attached a new VHD to a third VM, mounted as Z:, and setup the following virtual disks on it to use for the quorum and shared storage:

[image: img iSCSI Virtual Disks]

I can connect this this from sqlnode-01:

[image: iSCSI Initiator Properties]

I can only connect to it from sqlnode-02 if I first disconnect from sqlnode-01.

**Is this expected behaviour or should I be able to connect from both at the same time? – And see the storage from Computer Management on both servers at the same time?**

If I use the validation checker from Failover Cluster Manager I see the following:

[image: Validation check]

All following tests are Not Applicable – presumably as it hasn’t found any disks to be validated.
I get the same results whether I’ve left the disks offline or brought them online.

**Is there something obvious I might have missed when setting up the iSCSI target?**

The validation report states:

> Physical disk {82996b53-d867-4086-993c-7813c8f5e154} is visible from
>   only one node and will not be tested. Validation requires that the
>   disk be visible from at least two nodes. The disk is reported as
>   visible at node: sqlnode-01.corp.local

[image: Validation report]

Answer (score 6):

Take something like Starwinds and create Highly Available shared storage with your two nodes. AFAIR, they have a lot of manuals which may help you. BTW, it's for free.

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san#VSAN-FREE

Answer (score 1):

I'm ashamed to say that a reboot made this problem go away! My host machine crashed, meaning that the VM hosting the iSCSI target, and the two machines that needed to connect, all rebooted.

For reference, both nodes accessing the iSCSI should be able to connect at the same time - this is required for Failover Cluster Manager to let you use the storage.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, you should accept an answer (this answer), so the question will appear as solved on SE.